# How to insert data into my new create table in any method?

Tags: table

Clear like the title.
I want to insert data into my new create table.
How to write code, with what method?

**Please help me, thanks!**

Answer (score 3):

Magento **use MVC structure**,So you need to create a custom module,**which are  an installer script and a model**

- First create a  database table using installer script.
- Then create a model for this table.
- Now using model you can save your data at database.

See more details at

- [Create an magento extension with custom database table](http://www.amitbera.com/create-an-magento-extension-with-custom-database-table/)
- [Magento – Install, install upgrade, data and data upgrade
  scripts](http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-install-install-upgrade-data-and-data-upgrade-scripts/)

Assume that you have using  first referecne then  for insert a new record  at table you can use below code:

```
$model=Mage::getModel('custommodule/custommodule');
$model->setData('product_id',12);
$model->setData('customer_name','Testin test');
$model->setData('customer_email','dev.amitbera@gmail.com');
$model->setData('question','Why?');
...
$model->save(); /* use save() for save data at table */
```

Comment: Thanks, Amit Bera! My situation is different, my data is an array of multiple data. Finally, I got it by method 'insertOnDuplicate()'.